# Change Angular Material Dialog style

Tags: angular, angularjs, angular-material, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to create a modal with angular material dialog, but I would like to override the style of angular material with Bootstrap modal style...i'm trying to use 'panelClass' but the style is not applied...

Has anyone already encountered this problem?

This is my parent code

```
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ConfirmModalComponent, {
      data: { title: 'Eliminazione modulo', paragraph: 'Sei sicuro di voler eliminare il modulo' + name, buttonText: 'Conferma' },
      panelClass: ['modal-dialog', 'modal-dialog-centered']
    });
```

my modal code

```
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h1 mat-dialog-title class="modal-title">{{ this.data.title }}</h1>
  </div>
  <div mat-dialog-content class="modal-body">
    <p>{{ this.data.paragraph }}</p>
  </div>
  <div mat-dialog-actions class="modal-footer">
    <button
      class="btn btn-primary mx-conf-button me-2"
      [mat-dialog-close]="result"
    >
      <span>{{ this.data.buttonText }}</span>
    </button>
    <button class="btn btn-outline-danger" (click)="this.onClose()">
      Chiudi
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Make sure you've imported Bootstrap CSS in your project. You can do this by adding the following line to your styles.css or styles.scss file:
@import '~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

Comment: yep, I'm using a bootstrap custom theme and it is imported correctly, i can't override angular material theme

Comment: Are you using a component style? If yes you can try to move it at global level

Comment: no, I'm not using component style

Answer (score 0):

```
@media screen and (min-width: 501px) {
  ::ng-deep .custom-modalbox {
    .mdc-dialog {
      padding: 20px !important;
      width: 900px;
    }
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  ::ng-deep .custom-modalbox {
    .mdc-dialog {
      padding: 20px !important;
      width: 90%;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
  }
}

::ng-deep .custom-modalbox-min .custom-modalbox {
  mat-dialog-container {
    padding: 0;
  }

  .modal-header {
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: start !important;
    padding: 8px 20px !important;
  }

  .mdc-dialog__title {
    padding: 0px !important;
  }

  .mat-mdc-dialog-container .mdc-dialog__title {
    font-family: "Nunito Sans", sans-serif !important;
    font-size: 1.25rem !important;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: var(--phoenix-gray-800) !important;
  }

  .mat-mdc-dialog-container .mdc-dialog__content {
    font-family: "Nunito Sans", sans-serif !important;
  }

  .mdc-dialog__content {
    padding: 10px, 20px !important;
  }

  .mat-mdc-dialog-actions {
    justify-content: end !important;
  }

  .mdc-dialog__actions {
    padding: 8px 20px 20px 20px !important;
  }
}

@media media and (min-width: 501px) {
  ::ng-deep .custom-modalbox-min {
    .mdc-dialog {
      padding: 20px !important;
      width: 600px;
    }
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  ::ng-deep .custom-modalbox-min {
    .mdc-dialog {
      //padding: 20px !important;
      width: 90%;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: edit and add this css code in your component css file